# Where can I purchase video codecs for Ubuntu?

Tags: video, codecs

Where can I purchase video codecs for Ubuntu rather than downloading video codecs from an unknown source? I would like to purchase it.

Comment: You can get them for free from Ubuntu offical repo.

Comment: What do you mean by "*from an unknown source*?" It seems the same source as the rest of your system.

Comment: My previous version of Linux when I installed it suggested I purchase the codes

Comment: What was your previous version of Linux?